# How to split div rotation on mouse hover into 2 phases (slow, then fast)?

Tags: css

I have a div with the following hover effect:  `transform: rotateY(180deg);` so it's a container that flips on mouse hover. How can I make it so that instead of rotating instantly 180deg, it would slowly rotate 10deg, and then if the mouse is still hovering it, 180deg?

```
.flip-card-inner {
       transition: transform 0.6s;
       transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }

  .flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }
```

Comment: try adding transition, can you share some code in order to give accurate answer,

Comment: @SHAHILMISHRA thanks I added the code. How can I use transition for the same property? so basically it should have 1s transitioned to transform: rotateY(10deg), and then 1s transition to transform: rotateY(180deg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by making an `animation` instead of a `transition`.

Make sure to use `animation-fill-mode: forwards` so that the `animation` stays in place until you stop the `:hover`. I used `30deg` for demonstration purposes.

In your `animation`, make sure it starts on `transform: rotateY(0deg)` so it animates from `0deg` to `30deg` as well (optionally you could just apply `transform: rotateY(0deg)` directly on `.flip-card-inner` and start the `animation` at `@keyframe 10%`).

Play a bit with the `@keyframes` values and the `animation-duration`-property to adjust it to your liking.

```css
.flip-card:hover>.flip-card-inner {
  /* Shorthand for animation-name, animation-duration, animation-fill-mode */
  animation: flip 2s forwards;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

@keyframes flip {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotateY(30deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotateY(30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">card</div>
</div>
```